# How to mimic onPreferenceChanged() using Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener

Tags: android, android-preferences, android-jetpack, android-settings

Android Jetpack Preferences has a click listener `Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener` and preference change listener `Preference.OnPreferenceChangeListener`. However, there isn't any listener for when a value is **changed**, i.e a listener which is called whenever a preference is *successfully* updated.

**Usecase**

I have a background service which does a huge work. It starts from multiple places and down the road it reads a value from `SharedPreferences`.

Now, the problem is, when the service starts from `OnPreferenceChange()` and try to read `SharedPreferences` value, the value isn't updated yet.

```
  override fun onPreferenceChange(preference: Preference?, newValue: Any?): Boolean {

    // here newValue is of no use
     startService()

    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
val sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context)
sharedPreferences.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener { _, _ -> 
        startService()
}
```

This should be called after the preference was changed